# Click is not work on a certain zoom level on Retina Screen - Mac OS X

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, retina-display

**Note**: It is working 100% on a none retina screen external monitors, but not in my Mac Book Pro.

[image]

---

I have a weird situation where my click is not working on retina screen on 90%, 100%, 110% zoom on Retina Screen on my Mac OS X, It only works on 75% zoom.

[image]

What control this issues ? CSS ? or JS ?

Is there anything that I can do to avoid these issues ?

This is the code for it

## HTML

```
<div class="col-sm-2 " style="display: block;">
    <h5>Agent</h5>
    <span class="fa circle-icon fa-2x agent" circle-name="agent">
        <img src="/img/agent.png" width="30px">
    </span>
    <div class="line" style="display: none;"></div>
    <div class="options" style="display: none;">

        <input type="text" class="search" name="">
        <i class="fa fa-plus float-right btn btn-sm btn-success"></i>
        <br><br><br>

    </div>
    <div class="selected" style="display: none;"></div>
</div>
```

---

```
<i class="fa fa-plus float-right btn btn-sm btn-success"></i>
```

---

## jQuery

```
$('.device').on("click", function() {

    let circle = $(this);
    let currentOptions = circle.next().next('.options');
    let currentPlusSign = currentOptions.find('.fa-plus');

    .... more codes .... 

    currentPlusSign.on("click", function(event) {
        $('#'+selector+'Modal').modal('show');
        .... more codes .... 
    });

});
```

## Result

[image]

Comment: Do you have any working example where possible to check it?
Also are you sure that element with on click get user event and don't covered with some other div\someelement?

Comment: @m0rg0t : As you can see, that my `<i class="fa fa-plus ...` is in a div.

Comment: I also add a live video for you guys to see what exactly what I mean;